# "Could not buffer value as string" when copying with MLCP

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I'm copying from one database to another with mlcp and getting intermittent "Could not buffer value as string" errors like:

```
21/01/15 16:27:52 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentReader: RuntimeException reading 
[document URI] :java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not buffer value as string
21/01/15 16:27:52 INFO contentpump.DatabaseContentReader: host name: [my host name]
21/01/15 16:27:53 INFO contentpump.DatabaseContentReader: Retrying connect
```

So far, all the documents that have failed are .xml files, but they're not unreasonably large, less than 500 kB. They all seem to be valid XML as far as I can tell.

My first attempt had timeouts, so I changed both `buffer_size` and `thread_count` to 1. Java is allocated 16 GB RAM, which should be plenty, and neither the source nor destination nodes appear to be under any significant load.

What do these errors actually mean and how can I prevent them?

Comment: Are there any corresponding log messages on the server ErrorLog.txt or any failed requests in the AccessLog? Wondering if there may have been a timeout or other exception that caused MLCP response stream processing to have been broken.

Comment: You might also look at how much memory MLCP is consuming, and try increasing the allocated heap space

Comment: There are no errors in the port's xxxx_ErrorLog.txt or the server's ErrorLog.txt. The AccessLog's have a number of HTTP 401 and 200 responses, which seem to be in pairs, but I think that's normal? This port is using digest authentication.

Comment: Okay, yes with DIGEST you will see a 401 with the nonce in the reply and then another request made with that nonce(and hopefully 200 response). I was just wondering if there might have been any timeouts or other issues, but it doesn’t sound like it. So maybe look at MLCP client memory utilization and limits?

Comment: I increased the max Java heap space to 32 GB and tried again, still with errors. On some of the same files, I think, which is suspicious. But I added a query to the mlcp parameters to copy only one problematic file over and it succeeded.